# BadArgument, regex is malformed

Tags: regex, azure-language-understanding

Hello I'm currently importing a lot of regular expressions to a LUIS application but I get a malformed error in this one in particular:

```
(((re|)imprim|comprobante|ti(ck|q|qu)e)(?:[\S]*[\s]*){0,5}(pag(o|a|e|u)|operaci(o|ó)|transacci|movimien))|(\b(pag(o|a|e|u)|operaci(o|ó)|transacci|movimien)(?:[\S]*[\s]*){0,8}((re|)imprim|comprobante|ti(ck|q|qu)e))
```

I did not write that regex but I can't see anything wrong with it, what is the cause of this and how can I fix it?

Comment: That's a *long* regex

Comment: No syntax error. What flavor does luis support?

Comment: changing the \s* to \s+ and some lazy matching causes less backtracking? F.e.  `\b(((re)?imprim|comprobante|ti(cke|qu?e))((\S*\s+){0,5}?)(pag[aeou]|operaci[oó]|transacci|movimien))|((pag[aeou]|operaci[oó]|transacci|movimien)(\S*\s+){0,8}?((re)?imprim|comprobante|ti(cke|qu?e)))`

Comment: Has the issue been fixed?

Comment: Yeah I tried uploading the LUIS app again and it accepted it :P